# Style a wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid, styles

I have found a sample style for wpf as per below, the main thing it does is to change the background color of DataGridColumnHeader and still preserve the sorting arrow. as can be seen the sorting arrow is explicitly specified in the style as UpArrow and DownArrow.

```
<Style x:Key="SuojiHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HeaderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <dg:DataGridHeaderBorder SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}"
                                 IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                 IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                 IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}"
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                 Padding ="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                 SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}"
                                 SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
                    </dg:DataGridHeaderBorder>

                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderLeftGripperStyle}"/>

                    <Path Name="UpArrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="7,0,7,0" Visibility="Hidden">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <LineSegment Point="6,0"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="3,5"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="0,0"/>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Name="DownArrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="7,0,7,0" Visibility="Hidden">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,5">
                                    <LineSegment Point="6,5"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="3,0"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="0,5"/>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                        <Setter TargetName="UpArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DownArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                        <Setter TargetName="DownArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="UpArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

when I apply this style to my DataGrid

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" x:Name="MasterAllGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            HeadersVisibility="All"  CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#f0f0f0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#f0f0f0" ColumnHeaderStyle ="{StaticResource SuojiHeaderStyle}"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="MasterAllGrid_SelectionChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{x:Null}">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ticker" Binding="{Binding Path=Ticker}"/>
```

the arrow in the style overlapps with the Column Header Text (Sorry I am not allowed to posed pic by StackOverflow because I am new). How to make it not to overlap?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**For style wpf datatgrid you can use this resource dictionary**

```
<ResourceDictionary 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"

>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush_DataGridHeaderBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF1C7CB1" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF004A83" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush_DataGridHeaderMouseOverBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF1C7CAF" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF042A68" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush_DataGridHeaderBorder" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF1B577E" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF083258" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush_DataGridHeaderSortedBorder" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#B58801" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#681900" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush_DataGridHeaderSortedBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#C46007" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#AF2600" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush_DataGridSelected" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF3E4854" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF5D6670"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_DataGridSelectedForeground" Color="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush_DataGridAltRowBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE1FFEE" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC3F9DA" Offset="0.992"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="Style_HeaderGripper" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Background="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridHeaderSortedBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridHeaderSortedBorder}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Path x:Name="SortArrow" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1 z" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="1" Width="8" Height="6" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.4" />
                    <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="#AAC377" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <Rectangle Width="1" Margin="0,0,1,0" Fill="#425B10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource Style_HeaderGripper}"/>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource Style_HeaderGripper}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridHeaderMouseOverBackground}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridHeaderBorder}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="DisplayIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>



<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,6,0" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>

<!-- DataGridRow -->

<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridRow}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border 
          x:Name="DGR_Border"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid x:Name="selectiveScrollingGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="dataGridCellsPresenter" 
              Grid.Column="1"
               ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
               SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <DataGridRowHeader x:Name="dataGridRowHeader" 
              SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"  
              Grid.RowSpan="2"
              Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}}"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="Details" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Gray">
                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="dataGridDetailsPresenter" />
                        </Grid>
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="DGR_Border" Value="{DynamicResource BlueWindow}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="dataGridCellsPresenter" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="dataGridRowHeader" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" TargetName="dataGridRowHeader" Value="13.333"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridSelectedForeground}" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="dataGridDetailsPresenter" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" TargetName="dataGridCellsPresenter" Value="14.667"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="DGR_Border" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_DataGridSelected}"/>

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- DataGrid -->

<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGrid}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridAltRowBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Name="DG_ScrollViewer">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridHeaderBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridHeaderBorder}" BorderThickness="0,1" />
                                    <Button 
                    Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" 
                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=RowHeaderActualWidth}"
                    Focusable="false"
                    OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                   >
                                        <Button.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Border Background="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridHeaderBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Brush_DataGridHeaderBorder}" BorderThickness="0,1">
                                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="4" Fill="#3000" Width="11" Height="11" Stretch="Fill" Data="M1,0 L1,1 0,1 z"/>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="#AAC377" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                                    <Rectangle Width="1" Margin="0,0,1,0" Fill="#425B10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Button.Template>
                                    </Button>
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter 
                    Grid.Column="1"                         
                    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}}"/>
                    <!-- JAIMER removed from above
                    SourceScrollViewerName="DG_ScrollViewer" -->
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />
                                    <ScrollBar 
                    Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                     Orientation="Vertical"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                     Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar 
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                      Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                      ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                      Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                      Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: where we need to create Resource Dictionary, means where it resides??

Comment: How did you get these keys? they don't show up when I edit the template via VS or Blend.

Comment: Just spent a couple hours building my own template to then find this which looks far better... thanks very much :) +1 and hope others find this before attempting to make a custom style themselves

Comment: Change <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="DGR_Border" Value="{DynamicResource BlueWindow}"/> to <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="DGR_Border" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_DataGridSelected}"/> if you get an error when mousing over a row.